Batch Script or CMD Only Able to Process 70 Files at Once?
I made a script for vgmstream that decodes audio streams with some custom options like the output path and logging. I have noticed that the script terminates in the terminal if I exceed using more than 70 files with it, worth noting: I have many similar projects and they suffer from the same issue. Is there an issue in my code or is this an intrinsic limitation of the Windows command processor?

title vgmstream Decoder

md "%~dp1vgmstream" & cls
for %%f in (%*) do (
(
echo [%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4% @ %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%]
echo Infile: %%~nxf
echo Size: %%~zf bytes
echo Codec: WAV
echo Outfile: %%~nf.wav
echo.
)>>"%~dp1vgmstream\vgmstream.log"
"%~dp0vgmstream-cli.exe" %%f -o "%~dp1vgmstream\%%~nf.wav"
)
start "" notepad "%~dp1vgmstream\vgmstream.log"


Does it fail after the 70th file, or does it fail at the start when there are 70 files? Also, have you tried to substitute for with forfiles its a different instruction set and maybe it can handle 70+ files.

After 70 files, and forfiles doesn't seem to work or be compatible in my implementation @LPChip.

What happens if you try to change to

The result is identical @Io-oI.

Thanks for testing and commenting... what are the arguments passed in %*? Are your .wav files mono or stereo?

%*, as I understand it, is used to handle more than one infile. It is however many or whatever files are either selected from my custom shell in the context menu, or are being dragged and dropped. Channels also shouldn't matter, vgmstream has never had issue with this regardless of the file. Also as stated in my question: This issue is present in other near-identical scripts I have written for different programs including ffmpeg.

@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

>nul 2>&1 mkdir "%~dp1vgmstream"
title <nul & title vgmstream Decoder

set "_out=%~dp1vgmstream\%%%%~nG.wav"
set "_log=%~dp1vgmstream\vgmstream.log"
set "_vgmstream=%~dp0vgmstream-cli.exe"

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in =;(` 
      "dir /b /a:-d "%~dp1*.wav""
    `);= do >>"%_log%" =;(
         echo/[%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4% @ %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%]
         echo/Infile: %%~nxG
         echo/Size: %%~zG bytes
         echo/Codec: WAV
         echo/Outfile: %%~nG.wav
         echo/ 
        );= && call "%_vgmstream%" "%~dp1%%~nxG" -o "%_out%"

"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /t 5 | start "" /b notepad "%_log%"


I have the feeling that your problem is in your arguments. I suspect that you are passing your files (several + 70 of them) as an argument for processing in your bat, this confirmed, it generates a very long line, which, due to limitations, ends up supporting/meeting the limit that reaches the first 70 files/arguments.
As they are processed by the for loop, I suggest that you treat the argument in a for /f loop, processing popr filters your files exclusively with the .wav eXtension, and not one by one in a simple for loop argument by argument.


Command-line string limitation

Additional resources:

Dir /?
For /?
For /F /?

For /F commands


Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Commands Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, etc.


Set variable=start,end | DOS - String Manipulation
How does the Windows Command Interpreter [cmd.exe] Parse Scripts


There are some issues with this in testing so far. 1. Even using a single file does not result in decoding. 2. The log file is not generated, and notepad throws a file not found error when attempting to open it. 3. Using a large sum of files results in the following error: The filename or extension is too long.
All of these occurred under identical testing and use circumstances, if I am unable to either drag-and-drop, or invoke from the context menu after selecting files this solution will not be amicable but I thank you for your effort regardless.

you can try this command: dir /b *>logfile.txt after putting the txt file in pastbin and I will check your file name layout

You save the bat in the same folder where you have the binary and invoke and drag and drop a wav file... did you test it this way?

But I guarantee you that dragging several files and dropping them into a bat you have a problem with the length of the argument strings (1,2,3,4--n) adding up, and if you use the shell context menu, it doesn't work with any more of an argument...

Yes, I stored your script in the same location as my original; In the working directory for vgmstream.

I used the latest version of vgmstream, saved the bat like current post, passed thefile.cmd "d:\the\fullpath\to\wavfile.wav" and processed 180 files from the source folder to %~dp1vgmstream without any error. Could you please post a screenshot of the screen error and code used? plz!

I added a pause at the end of the script because it was just terminating with no results, this is the error I got in the terminal with pause enabled: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). I even tried making a secondary script that calls yours with a static path to a specific file, I am getting the same error. Interestingly. when notepad attempts to open the non-existent file it is at least stating it should be in the expected path.

Are there multiple dots in the names in your files?

No, the names are all serialized with numeric names.

are all files to process : .wav extension?

In my original implementation from my question: Yes. I have been using the same files, from the same location throughout my own testing in addition to your proposals.
